# Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-universal

I used angular universal according to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering) article (an article that publishes at wiki angular-cli). all of the steps work fine but in last step (npm run serve:ssr) below error shows:

After packaging, the loading page will appear this situation:

Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
at vendor.0d1ec0a758.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
at app.ec87183347.js:1

I use angular 4.0.0 and this line is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "roxo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod -a home && ng build --prod -a server --output-hashing=false",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --display-entrypoints --progress --colors"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "angular2-persian-pipes": "0.0.6",
    "bootstrap.native": "^2.0.19",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jalali-moment": "^2.1.3",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "lg-autoplay": "^1.0.4",
    "lg-fullscreen": "^1.0.1",
    "lg-hash": "^1.0.4",
    "lg-pager": "^1.0.2",
    "lg-share": "^1.1.0",
    "lg-thumbnail": "^1.1.0",
    "lg-video": "^1.2.0",
    "lg-zoom": "^1.1.0",
    "lightgallery": "^1.6.6",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^3.0.3",
    "ng-spin-kit": "^5.1.1",
    "ng2-carouselamos": "^3.2.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.1.9",
    "ng2-jalali-date-picker": "^2.0.3",
    "ng2-typewriter": "^1.1.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.9.3",
    "ngx-carousel": "^1.3.3",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^6.2.1",
    "primeng": "^4.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "persian-date": "^1.0.1",
    "primeng": "^4.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.7.1",
    "video.js": "^6.6.3"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me on the above issue, please?